# When and why is std::binary_semaphore more performant than std::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, concurrency, semaphore, condition-variable

According to the [C++20 semaphore docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore), semaphores can be used in a similar manner to condition variables:

> Semaphores are also often used for the semantics of
> signalling/notifying rather than mutual exclusion, by initializing the
> semaphore with ​0​ and thus blocking the receiver(s) that try to
> acquire(), until the notifier "signals" by invoking release(n). In
> this respect semaphores can be considered alternatives to
> std::condition_variables, **often with better performance.**

Emphasis mine. I've used semaphores in this manner in Java and Swift in the past, but in C++, I've normally resorted to using `std::condition_variable` for this signal/notify pattern. With C++20, I now have access to `std::binary_semaphore`, and I'm wondering what the difference is.

When does a semaphore (in particular, `std::binary_semaphore`) have better performance than using `std::condition_variable` in the same manner, and why?

Comment: The fact that `condition_variable` requires explicitly using a `mutex` while `binary_semaphore` does not should clue you into the difference.

Comment: **Profile** the difference on your platform.  When you are on a platform that the architecture supports a more performant binary_semaphore, and your use case can be fulfilled by its limitations, then it will be more performant.